# DAX to follow the hyperlink - Power BI

Tags: hyperlink, powerbi, dax, slicers

I'm trying to use Hierarchy Slicer as a Navigation Tool in Power BI. This slicer is getting hierarchical values from a table (Root > Fist Child > Second Child > Third Child etc). Each node in the table (Excel file) contains a URL field.

I'm trying to get this URL by using a Measure.

Is there any possibility that when clicked on the hierarchy slicer a user can be taken to that URL (of the selected value)?

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What you are seeking for is a bookmark functionality (direct you somewhere on click). This functionality is not implemented in Slicer but you can do work-around. For example, add a button right next to your slicer.

Comment: the issue is this slicer get dynamic values for each report we need to go to. Can't hard coded all these bookmarks. Adding a button is definitely an option but not too desirable.

Comment: What about:
OPTION A)
1. Enable single-select
2. Add a Table visualization on the right with a field that allows you to do a Drill-through and bring the filter with you on another page?
OPTION B)
1. Enable single-select
2. Add a Table visualization on the right with the URL field so user can click on it and follow the URL?

Comment: Thanks for your time Seymour,
The project comprises of around 80 different Single page reports. By keeping their URLs in a SQL table and picking them up directly (at runtime by a measure) will allow us to manage all reports from single location (keeping pages/reports off line, adding a new version etc) - only by working on the SQL table.

Although not shown in the image, some hierarchies run 9 levels deep. It will be a single select no doubt. However, keeping them in a table visual won't allow us to have a hierarchical structure or will it?

Continued...

Comment: Hierarchical slicer is the closest I can find to the description. The main issue is how to take an Action when user clicks on any item in the hierarchy? Using DAX or any other? Can we find any solution by using Python (can we modify and build upon Hierarchy Slicer?)

Comment: The 80 different single pages are completely different pages (different fact tables, different measures and different dimensions) or is it the same page (same fact tables, same visualizations, etc) pre-filtered for a specific attribute value?

Comment: That's the beauty, they all are connected to a single data model (cube) and only a couple of parameters are passed along.

Comment: It still not completely clear to me the situation but assuming the 80 pages in reality is always the same page but pre-filtered for a specific attribute value, I would get rid of 79 pages and keep only one page combined with the drill-through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-drillthrough

Comment: Oh No, my apologies for not being cleared earlier. They're not the same and pre-filtered. These each page show a different perspective of the report. Explaining the image above: if you're at AE_Tiles level you'll have 4 different Hierarchy path to go to (AE_Margin, Inventory, Revenue, S&P). Should you chose AE_Margin, the page you land on will provide you 2 options to go to from there By Drivers and By SL Hierarchy.

All of these become 80 different pages.

Comment: Ok clear. Than I suggest my first proposal:
1. force single select slicer
2. use a table containing the relate URL for the slicer selection https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-hyperlinks-in-tables      Next, I would think how to enhance UX/UI for example by adding a text measure to use as a message for the user "Please select a slicer value". And also another slicer to fliter the table in order to show nothing in the case user has not selected any slicer value.

Comment: Yes that would be a solution but it doesn't give us Hierarchical structure and I believe dynamic indentation in tables is not yet possible?

Comment: Why would you need a hierarchical structure in the table? In the end each combination is associated to one and only one URL. Therefore we will use the table only as a hyperlink to the Page associated to that slicer filter value.

Comment: There is a huge difference between putting hyperlinks in the table and presenting the report structure in a collapsible/expendable format (like hierarchy slicers or some other similar way). When you mentioned putting URLs in the table, I then pointed out indentation but it won't work.

Comment: Try to explain what do you mean. Could you please also post an example of the data source for the slicer and corresponding URL so it is easier finding a technical implementation?